# how to Render Controls from CodeBehind into a specific Panel

Tags: web-part, jquery, visual-web-part

I'm in the process of working thorugh Microsofts video tutorials for developing on Sharepoint. My actual small project is to create a visual Webpart which displays a list of all registered users with their display name, department and title.

This works like a charm. Now I want to improve the design of this little piece, just for the sake of it. So I created an .
How can I put my rendered controls right into this Panel?

Below is the code which is executed when the Page loads.

```
public partial class PeoplePickerUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _department = null, _Title = null;
        var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site);
        var userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

        Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='ui-widget-header'>PeoplePicker<div class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'>"));
        foreach (UserProfile userProfile in userProfileManager)
        {
            if (userProfile[PropertyConstants.Department].Value != null)
                _department = userProfile[PropertyConstants.Department].Value.ToString();
            else _department = "";
            if (userProfile[PropertyConstants.Title].Value != null)
                _Title = userProfile[PropertyConstants.Title].Value.ToString() + ", ";
            else _Title = "";

            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p><fieldset>"+ " " +"<a href='" + userProfile.PublicUrl + "'>"+ userProfile.DisplayName + "</a><br />" 
                + _Title +  _department + "</fieldset></p>"));
        }
        Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div></div>"));
    }
}

<asp:Panel ID="staffContentInHerePanel" runat="server">
   // Content should be put in here
</asp:Panel>
```

As you can see I am rendering two divs, which I want to be styled with JQuery. This part shall be exported into the .ascx file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **staffContentInHerePanel.Controls** instead of just **Controls** in your code

Something like this...

```
staffContentInHerePanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div></div>"));
```

Comment: Simple as that, Works like charm.
I'd like to vote you up, but I'm lacking reputation.

best regards.